# Items not being found in search box even though they exist

Tags: vba, excel

So basically I have a search box setup in Sheet 2 where I use a barcode scanner to scan the item IDs and when I hit search it populates the information about that item that is found in Sheet 1. I have 2 types of item IDs in the system, one which consists of letters and numbers and the other strictly numbers. The problem I am currently encountering is that when I scan the strictly number ID into my search box, it cannot find it, but it can find it if I just copy and paste the ID from sheet 1 into the search box. I feel as if it has something to do with formatting of my search, like maybe its just looking for text and when I copy and paste into the search box they are formatted as text? I'm not too sure but any insight would be greatly appreciated. Attached below is my code.

```
Sub SearchBox()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, x As Long
Dim count As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
i = Sheets("Gages").Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For x = 2 To lastrow

If Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Cells(x, 1) = Sheets("Gages").Range("A1") Then
    Sheets("Gages").Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 7).Value = Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Cells(x, 1).Resize(, 7).Value
    i = i + 1
    count = count + 1
End If

Next x


If count = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Cannot Find Gage, Please check Gage ID")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe try using the trim() function

Comment: @sourceCode Where would I insert that into my code?

Comment: all the trim function does is remove leading and trailing blanks spaces. I thought that could be the issue. put the desired value in as arguments to the trim function to see if thats the issue

Comment: Could you maybe update your post to include output, it would help in the debugging process

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere the text/value isn't equal. I inserted a msgbox in your code so you can see exactly what's being compared.

**UPDATED WITH TRUE/FALSE DISPLAYED IN MESSAGE BOX TITLE**

```
    Sub SearchBox()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, x As Long
Dim count As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
i = Sheets("Gages").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For x = 2 To lastrow

'try with this to test
Dim anSwer As Integer

Dim TrueOrFalse As String
TrueOrFalse = Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Cells(x, 1) = Sheets("Gages").Range("A1")

anSwer = MsgBox("your value in Charlotte Gauges Cell " & Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Cells(x, 1).Address & " is """ & Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Cells(x, 1).Value & _
 """ while your other value in cell " & Sheets("Gages").Range("A1").Address & " is """ & Sheets("Gages").Range("A1").Value & """. Continue?", vbYesNo, Title:=TrueOrFalse)
If anSwer = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
End If
'End of test code, this can be deleted once you figure out your issue

If Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Cells(x, 1) = Sheets("Gages").Range("A1") Then
    Sheets("Gages").Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 7).Value = Sheets("Charlotte Gages").Cells(x, 1).Resize(, 7).Value
    i = i + 1
    count = count + 1
End If

Next x


If count = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Cannot Find Gage, Please check Gage ID")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The message box is working perfectly, I still can't see where my problem is as the ones I am looking for are at about 4000 rows down and I do not want to click Yes 4000 times

Comment: Wrap an if statement before it for when i= 4000 to launch the messagebox.

Comment: @Jmaragno glad it worked. It would be most appreciated if you clicked "accept" for this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was wrong. The number-only ID's were stored as text in Sheet 1, therefore not allowing my search box to find it. All I had to do was convert them all to numbers and it fixed everything.

Comment: Seriously? You're going to post your own answer and not even give mine a click up, even though you clearly used it to debug your issue? My answer was exactly correct in saying you had some difference between the cells you were comparing.